# Where to store custom objects?

Tags: python, scripting, blender

I'm confused about where to store custom python objects (of not just basic type -- so cannot be stored as blender properties).

What I'm trying to achieve is this: I want to accomplish a heavy computation that can be started by pressing a button (operator) and can be paused by pressing the same button. The computation simply creates/modifies the object that I was talking about. Hence I want to store that object somewhere so that when I execute the operator again, work can be paused/resumed on the same object.

I've tried to store this object in `self` and `context` while in execute procedure of the operator, however both gets changed on the next call. So where else can I store the half-processed object? Or, is there anything better to accomplish pause/resume functionality?

Comment: Voted to close as off-topic: not a graphic design question (3d is explicitly not in scope, and this is about application scripting, not design in any case)

Comment: I'm sorry, I blundered Graphic Design with Computer Graphics :)

Answer (score 0):

You might look into pickling. http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem is not related to serialization, but *where* to store the references of objects (created at runtime) inside blender so that they can be used later. (By *later* I don't mean after restarting Blender, just later in the program)